# how to display upcoming birthdays with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i need to display 5 nearest birthdays including today date. My model is look like

```
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    roles: [{type: String, ref: 'Role'}],
    birthDate: {type: Date, required: true}
})
```

I understand how to get all birthdays in current month, but i need to get 5 neariest from the whole year.

This is how i get all birhthdays from the current month

```
const users = await User.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $eq: [{$month: `$birthDate`}, {$month: new Date()}],
                        },
                    }
                }
            ])
```